# Li items of menu bar wraps to a new line ( liquid layout CSS)

Tags: css

I am trying to create a site using html,css,php & MySQL. I am trying to design a liquid layout, with a centred navigation menu, within the header. In google chrome, the design works well. but in firefox and IE, the end of list items drop down to a new line. How can I fix this issue?

I am attaching the code snippets below:

---

css style for menu:

```
.menu {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url(../images/menu_bg.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    min-width:750px;
    min-height:81px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    }

.menu ul{
    clear: both;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    left:50%;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

.menu > ul > li { 
     float:left;
     right: 50%;
     position:relative;
     list-style:none;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    display:block;
    color:#ff3;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:transparent;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a b {
    display:block;
    background:transparent;
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
}

**********************************

css styles for Header:


#header {
    background-image:url(../images/header_bg.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:160px;
    min-width:750px;
}

#logo {
    background-image:url(../images/logo.gif);
    background-position:10px 10px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:79px;
}

*******************************************************

body: 

<div id="header">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="../index.php"><b>Home</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="../about/about.php"><b>About Us</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="../services/services.php"><b>Services</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="../shop/shop.php"><b>Tech Shop</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="../downloads/downloads.php"><b>Downloads</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="../knowledge/knowledge.php"><b>Knowledge Base</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="../contact/contact.php"><b>Contact Us</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="../Livehelp/livehelp.php"><b>Live Help</b></a></li>
  </ul>   
  </div>
</div>
********************************
```

Comment: Please post the code on http://jsfiddle.net/ It will be easier to see the problem and modify the code to see how to correct it.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll do that and report back.

Answer (score -1):

Remove left:50%; and right:50%; They are meaningless

Comment: The question is foolish, so I will not waste time to it, simply I said mistakes that were in code

Comment: Well, the left:50% and right:50% in menu>ul and menu>ul>li was integral to implement a centred liquid menu as shown by Matthew James Taylor: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support.

Comment: As of now, the issue gets resolved either by increasing the minimum-width or using less number of menu li items. I was looking for an alternative solution. Thanks.